# Fetch image from url using file_get_contents

Tags: php, loops, header, logic, file-get-contents

This is my php code which is only fetching the first image out of 9, although when i check the URL manually all 9 image URL formed correctly, i tried this code with CURL too, but loop is not working, let me know what I am doing wrong ?

```
<?php

for($i=2 ; $i <= 10 ; $i++ ){
header('Content-type: image/jpeg;');
$url = "http://www.lafourchette.com/p-3.3.0/default/rate-bar-bg-".$i.".jpg";
$mycontent = file_get_contents($url);
echo $mycontent;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> @h2ooooooo actually bro im not looking for a single image ... i just want to save this 9 images in a folder

```
<?php
    for ($i = 2 ; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $imageName = "rate-bar-bg-" . $i . ".jpg";
        $imageContent = file_get_contents("http://www.lafourchette.com/p-3.3.0/default/" . $imageName);
        file_put_contents($imageName, $imageContent);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because it's not possible to concatenate JPEG images like that. The client will read the first image and treat the other images as trailing garbage.

If you want to create one big image, you should use [`GD`](http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [`imagick`](http://sg3.php.net/imagick).

Alternatively, you can create multiple images on the page that each point to `rate-bar-bg-2.jpg` thru `10`. This is likely to be more efficient, unless you have very good reasons not to link to that website directly.

Or, just do the work once and create a sprite manually.

Comment: then how could i make this to show all 9 images on single page ??

Comment: @swapnesh Couldn't you just make an HTML file with 9 `<img>` elements referring to the PHP file outputting these images one by one?

Comment: @h2ooooooo even i can save all 9 images just by little changing the URL ..... its not what im looking....i think its better if u provide some code rather than pointing me what i can do or not (sorry for being little rude with the words )

Comment: @swapnesh Then you should specify your answer better. This answer put you in the direction of GD of imagick, even with links to the documentation. If you want to make one big image of all these images, then that is the approach to go.

Comment: @h2ooooooo actually bro im not looking for a single image ... i just want to save this 9 images in a folder

Comment: @jack i will look into sprite ..although im very new to use it :(

Comment: @swapnesh Then use `$fileContent = file_get_contents("url")` and then `file_put_contents("image.jpg", $fileContent)`

Comment: @h2ooooooo post this as an answer this is what im looking for

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @h2ooooooo i came up with the solution ---

```
<?php

for($i=2 ; $i <= 10 ; $i++ ){
$filename = "rate-bar-bg-".$i.".jpg";
header('Content-type: image/jpeg;');
$url = "http://www.lafourchette.com/p-3.3.0/default/rate-bar-bg-".$i.".jpg";
$fileContent = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents($filename, $fileContent);
}
```

Comment: Though it doesn't quite do what the OP was asking for, it does make a file with the contents of the URL. If you named it with a `.html` extension it would open as a copy of the webpage - but be sure the original did not have any nasty scripts in it! However it is not an image. So far I have only got PDFCrowd to make images but I am working on it...html2img next...

Answer (score 0):

Set the content lenght as well

`header('Content-Length: ' . $size);`

Answer (score 0):

```
  for ($i = 2 ; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $imageName = "rate-bar-bg-" . $i . ".jpg";
        copy("http://www.lafourchette.com/p-3.3.0/default/" . $imageName,$imageName);
}
```